# Find matrix determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

How do I reduce this matrix to row echelon form and hence find the determinant, or is there a way that I am unaware of that finds the determinant of this matrix without having to reduce it row echelon form given this is all I know and there exists no additional information.

$\left[
  \begin{array}{ccc}
   1+x  & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
    1 & 2+x & 3 & 4 \\
    1 & 2 & 3+x & 4 \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4+x \\
  \end{array}
\right]$

Answer (score 3):

Let $A$ be the matrix in your question, then $x$ is an eigenvalue since $A-xI$ is clearly singular and the dimension of its corresponding eigenspace is $3$, hence $\lambda_{1} = \lambda_{2} = \lambda_{3} = x$. The trace is equal to the sum of its eigenvalues, so $\lambda_{4} = x+10$. Finally, the determinant is equal to the product of the eigenvalues so $\operatorname{det}(A) = x^{4}+10x^{3}$.

Comment: Sorry, what you wrote is true, I just got confuzed.

Comment: Sorry I haven't done eigenvalues and all that eigen stuff yet (we're meant to learn it next semester), is there another way? All I know is that you're supposed to multiply the diagonal entries of a row echelon square matrix to get the determinant.

Comment: @user117498 You can perform the usual cofactor expansion about any row or column, performing elementary row operations to the matrix can make it a little simpler but it would still be an exercise in some amount of brute forcing.

Answer (score 0):

Subtract $2\times$ first column from the second column, $3\times$ first column from the third and $4\times$ first column from the fourth column.

You get

$$\left|\begin{matrix}1+x & -2x & -3x & -4x\\
1 & x & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & x & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & x\end{matrix}\right|$$

Comment: I don't understand how this helps, because all I know is that you're supposed to multiply the diagonal entries of a row echelon square matrix to get the determinant.

Comment: @user117498 You can expand the determinant around any of the last $3$ columns or rows to get $2$ simple $3\times3$ determinants to calculate.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $f(x)=\Delta$. It's a fourth degree polynomial.

$C_1\to C_1+C_2+C_3+C_4\implies x+10 $ is a factor.

$f(0)=0\implies 0$ is a root.// Repeated Rows

$f'(0)=0+0+0+0\implies 0$ is again repeated.// Repeated Rows

$f''(0)=0\implies 0$ is again repeated.// Repeated Rows for last time.

This all $\implies f(x)=x^3(x+10)$. Its obvious that coefficient of $x^4$ must be $1$.

For differentiation, differentiate one row and treat others as constant(like product rule). Add them all. It's pretty easy to see that they have same rows(without even writing them).

Answer (score 0):

If you know how value of determinant is influenced by elementary row/column operations (see [ProofWiki](http://proofwiki.org/wiki/Effect_of_Elementary_Row_Operations_on_Determinant)) then you could start by adding all other columns to the last one (which does not change the determinant) and the rest is relatively easy:

$$
\begin{vmatrix}
   1+x  & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
    1 & 2+x & 3 & 4 \\
    1 & 2 & 3+x & 4 \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4+x
\end{vmatrix}=
\begin{vmatrix}
   1+x  & 2 & 3 & 10+x \\
    1 & 2+x & 3 & 10+x \\
    1 & 2 & 3+x & 10+x \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 10+x
\end{vmatrix}=
(x+10)
\begin{vmatrix}
   1+x  & 2 & 3 & 1 \\
    1 & 2+x & 3 & 1 \\
    1 & 2 & 3+x & 1 \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 1
\end{vmatrix}=
(x+10)
\begin{vmatrix}
    x & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & x & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & x & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{vmatrix}=(x+10)x^3
$$